# React styled components how to access state from child?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to figure out how to access state set in a child component in the parent component while using the .map function.

I would like to use a ternary in the map function to decide what icon to show in each item in my navbar when it is clicked.

I'm not sure how to get access to the visible state variable in the Navbar.Image

I hope this mess makes sense to someone.

```
export default function Navbar({ children, ...restProps }: IProps) {
  return (
    <Container {...restProps}>
      <Inner>
        <Navbar.List>
          {NavData.map((item, i) => (
            <Navbar.ListItem key={i}>
              <Navbar.Link>
                <Navbar.Image src={visible ? item.openIcon : item.closedIcon} /> <<<< HERE IS MY PROBLEM
                <p>{item.name}</p>
              </Navbar.Link>
            </Navbar.ListItem>
          ))}
        </Navbar.List>
      </Inner>
    </Container>
  );
}

Navbar.List = function NavbarList({ children, ...restProps }: IProps) {
  return <List {...restProps}>{children}</List>;
};

Navbar.ListItem = function NavbarListItem({ children, ...restProps }: IProps) {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Ctx.Provider value={{ visible, setVisible }}>
      <ListItem onClick={() => setVisible((curr) => !curr)} {...restProps}>
        {children}
      </ListItem>
    </Ctx.Provider>
  );
};

Navbar.Link = function NavbarLink({ children, ...restProps }: IProps) {
  return <Link {...restProps}>{children}</Link>;
};

Navbar.Image = function NavbarImage({ children, ...restProps }: IProps) {
  return <Image {...restProps} />;
};
```

Comment: You have to pass the `state` you need down to the child as a `prop`.

Comment: But I’m setting the state in the child called Navbar.ListItem so that when I use map in the parent then each item will have its own independent state.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I overlooked the Styled-Components part. You can't do what you're asking, sorry to say. It's a real pain. If you find out that I'm mistaken I'd be thrilled to know. The best you can do is to use traditional `classNames` set based on the states, and then use those in your styled-components styles. Note that my knowledge comes from Emotion and not Styled-Components so it _could_ be wrong, but they're almost completely interchangeable.